# Why can't I see the source code of a function within a function in R?

Tags: r

I am using some code, which has the following function:

```
> use_template
function (x, template, item = x$id) 
{
    assert_that(is_valid_output(x))
    renderer(x) <- new_renderer(template, item)
    return(x)
}
```

This function is able to be used successfully in the code.  However, when I try and view the source code for "`new_renderer`", which I presume is a custom function, I get this:

```
new_renderer
Error: object 'new_renderer' not found
```

The code clearly uses `new_renderer` successfully within this function - so why can't I view the source code for it?

Comment: From what package did you get the `new_renderer` function?

Comment: Try `getAnywhere(new_renderer)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be a function that is defined in the package but not exported. For example:

```
> usethis::use_template
function (template, save_as = template, data = list(), ignore = FALSE, 
    open = FALSE, package = "usethis") 
{
    template_contents <- render_template(template, data, package = package)
    new <- write_over(proj_path(save_as), template_contents)
    if (ignore) {
        use_build_ignore(save_as)
    }
    if (open && new) {
        edit_file(proj_path(save_as))
    }
    invisible(new)
}
<bytecode: 0x00000168a175c3b8>
<environment: namespace:usethis>
```

You can see a call to the function `render_template()`. However, if you try to call that function directly:

```
> usethis::render_template
 Error: 'render_template' is not an exported object from 'namespace:usethis'
```

It doesn't work! To understand why, you can look at the [source code](https://github.com/r-lib/usethis/blob/master/R/template.R). You should see that before the definition of `use_template()`, there is a big block of special comments that will become the documentation. However, `render_template()` is defined just below, without any comment or documentation. This is because `use_template()` is made available to the package user, whereas `render_template()` is meant for internal use only.

If you really want to see the code of that function, you can use a triple colon:

```
> usethis:::render_template
function (template, data = list(), package = "usethis") 
{
    template_path <- find_template(template, package = package)
    strsplit(whisker::whisker.render(read_utf8(template_path), 
        data), "\n")[[1]]
}
<bytecode: 0x00000168a33d7b98>
<environment: namespace:usethis>
```

This is practical to find the source code of a function, but you shouldn't use it to call the function: there is usually a reason for it to be hidden.

Answer (score 1):

As @Suren has pointed out, it will be suitable to know from which package comes `new_renderer`. To illustrate this, consider the following example, where we're going to nest the `lm` function from `stats` package inside a `custom_function`. Additionnally, we're going to describe the function by calling `body` and `deparse` on it.

```
require(stats)

custom_function <-
function(x, y) {

    result <- lm(x, y)
    
    return(result)

}
```

Now, to get the body of `custom_function` I would call `body` on it (alternatively `deparse`), the expected output is

```
deparse(custom_function)
>>> 
[1] "function (x, y) "       "{"                      "    result <- lm(x, y)"
[4] "    return(result)"     "}"  
body(custom_function)
>>> 
{
    result <- lm(x, y)
    return(result)}
```

Notice that `custom_function` is calling `lm`, which is a function of the `stats` package. Therefore, when I call `deparse` on lm, it will get the description (the source code of the nested function) of it.

```
deparse(lm)
>>> 
[1] "function (formula, data, subset, weights, na.action, method = \"qr\", "                           
 [2] "    model = TRUE, x = FALSE, y = FALSE, qr = TRUE, singular.ok = TRUE, "                          
 [3] "    contrasts = NULL, offset, ...) "                                                              
 [4] "{"                                                                                                
 [5] "    ret.x <- x"                                                                                   
 [6] "    ret.y <- y"        
...
...
```

If I only want to see the body of the function, I would call

```
body(lm)
>>> 
{
    ret.x <- x
    ret.y <- y
    cl <- match.call()
    mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
...
...
```

As conclusion, this approach worked out because we know from which package does the `lm` function comes from.